# Como usar CASE WHEN SUM() com GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case, sum

Criei a tabela `teste(id,nome)`:

[image: TABELA TESTE]

E a tabela `segunda(id,id_teste,valor,tipo)`:

[image: TABELA SEGUNDA]

No `SELECT` quero fazer um `GROUP BY id_teste` e somar o valor diferenciando pelo tipo, ou seja, quando o tipo for 1 quero que no `SELECT` a soma do valor seja colocado numa coluna `valorDoTipo1` e quando o tipo for 2 `valorDoTipo2`.

Porém no `SELECT` que fiz, não é o que está acontecendo:

```
SELECT teste.id,nome,
        CASE WHEN tipo=1 THEN
            SUM(valor)
        END AS valorDoTipo1, 
        CASE WHEN tipo=2 THEN
            SUM(valor)
        END AS valorDoTipo2
        FROM teste, segunda WHERE segunda.id_teste = teste.id GROUP BY teste.id
```

Ele está me dando um resultado de apenas 1 soma de valor:

[image: RESULTADO DO MEU SQL]

O resultado que procuro é este:

[image: RESULTADO ESPERADO]

E é dado por este `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT teste.id,nome,
    (SELECT SUM(valor) FROM segunda s2 WHERE s2.id_teste = s.id_teste AND tipo=1) AS valorDoTipo1,
    (SELECT SUM(valor) FROM segunda s2 WHERE s2.id_teste = s.id_teste AND tipo=2) AS valorDoTipo2
    FROM teste, segunda s WHERE s.id_teste = teste.id GROUP BY teste.id
```

Porém no meu caso real terei de aplicar isso num banco real e com muitos dados, o `select` ficou com mais de 5 segundos para ser executado, alguma solução para melhorar o meu primeiro `select`?

Comment: Em vez de imagens, seria melhor colocar as informações como texto mesmo - principalmente os dados das tabelas, assim as pessoas conseguem copiar e colar mais facilmente para poderem testar. Ver mais detalhes [no **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode transferir cada caso isolado para dentro da função de soma do SQL, e retornar em colunas separadas no momento da consulta, dependendo da necessidade.

Por exemplo:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = 1 THEN segunda.valor ELSE 0 END) AS valor1
```

Traduzindo: somar x (valor atual da soma) + y (valor da coluna, ou zero caso não satisfaça a condição).

SQL completo:

```
SELECT teste.id, teste.nome,
SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = 1 THEN segunda.valor ELSE 0 END) AS valorDoTipo1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = 2 THEN segunda.valor ELSE 0 END) AS valorDoTipo2
FROM teste
INNER JOIN segunda ON segunda.id_teste = teste.id
GROUP BY teste.id;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que estava procurando. Não tinha pensado em usar a condição dentro da soma. Novamente, agradeço.